# NTLM no longer working with Java WebStart following a Java upgrade

Tags: java, windows-authentication, java-web-start, ntlm

My company recently updated our Java client from JRE 1.8.0_111 to 1.8.0_211.

After the Java update, our Swing client application is no longer able to successfully perform Windows integrated authentication via NTLM.

[image: Java Login Prompt]

**Is there a new setting or code change needed to support NTLM in Java 1.8.0_211 or above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I have found the answer, which I am quoting from the post I found here:

[New net.properties property - jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth](https://answers.axonivy.com/questions/3659/java-8-update-201-authentication-window-on-startup)

**Answer:**

[image]

**Here is the excerpt from the net.properties, showing the updated property:**
`jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=trustedHosts`

[image]